# Not able to mock start-process powershell {} command?

Tags: powershell, unit-testing, pester

I am using a command where I am calling one ps1(dummy.ps1) file to another ps1 file,
command I am using is :

`start-process powershell{.\dummy.ps1}`

I need to write the pester unit test to cover this line and I have to mock it but it not happening , so please help me to sort this out.

I am writing the mock like this:

```
Mock start-process {}
```

in my test file.

Comment: "I have to mock it but it not happening" - show us your Mock

Comment: I am  writing like this: Mock start-process {} in my test file.

Comment: Any help on this will be very usefull. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with what you were attempting, although something may be wrong in the full context of your attempt.

I was able to mock start-process as follows:

```
    Describe 'tests involving start-process' {
        Context 'no mock' {
            It 'needs to be mocked' {
                # demonstrate that it's not mocked 
                # ... you'll have to dismiss the console window by hand
                start-process cmd "/c pause" | should -Be $null
            }
        }

        Context 'mocked' {
            Mock start-process {"fake execution"}

            It 'can be mocked' {
                start-process cmd "/c pause" | should -Be "fake execution"
            }
        }
    }
```

This yields the following output:

```
    > Invoke-Pester ".\test.tests.ps1"
        ____            __
       / __ \___  _____/ /____  _____
      / /_/ / _ \/ ___/ __/ _ \/ ___/
     / ____/  __(__  ) /_/  __/ /
    /_/    \___/____/\__/\___/_/
    Pester v4.9.0
    Executing all tests in '.\test.tests.ps1'

    Executing script .\test.tests.ps1

      Describing tests involving start-process

        Context no mock
          [+] needs to be mocked 27ms

        Context mocked
          [+] can be mocked 14ms
    Tests completed in 348ms
    Tests Passed: 2, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0, Pending: 0, Inconclusive: 0
```

Perhaps you need to install the latest Pester?  I updated to 4.9 with `install-module pester -force -skippublishercheck`